# Can I convert string to utf8_general_ci in javascript before using that in WHERE clause in Sequelize?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, sequelize.js

I'm using `sequelize` in my application and `MySql` as DB. I'm getting error `Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8mb4_unicode_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '='`
and this is the SQL query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `myTable` AS `myTarget` 
WHERE (`myTable`.`deletedAt` = '1970-01-01 00:00:00' 
     AND `myTarget`.`email` = 'someValueFromUserInput') 
LIMIT 1;
```

So I quess that `someValueFromUserInput` is sometimes different from what I have in DB table and that causes the Error. Can I somehow convert that value to `utf8_general_ci` to avoid such error? And what actually the error says - that `myTarget.email` is of `utf8_general_ci` or `utfmb4_unicode_ci`?

Comment: Strongly suggest you upgrade your database fields to utf8mb4.  Mysql's utf8 was a bad idea and is only still around for backwards compatibility, but should be avoided

Comment: @ysth would that fix the issue? And what should I set as value - utf8mb4_unicode_ci?

Comment: Specify the collation explicitly. For example, ```AND `myTarget`.`email` = 'someValueFromUserInput' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'```

Comment: *I quess that someValueFromUserInput is sometimes different from what I have in DB table and that causes the Error* The column uses column/table/database collation (what is first). Literal uses connection collation. They are different. Think about adjusting your connection settings. PS. ```myTable.`deletedAt` = '1970-01-01 00:00:00'``` may produce this error too. Use ```myTable.`deletedAt` = DATETIME '1970-01-01 00:00:00'``` (specify literal datatype and, hence, operation context explicitly).

Comment: can you show output of `show create table myTable`?  I had thought the problem was the table using the bad utf8 character set, but perhaps it is the connection, as Akina seems to be suggesting.  If I am correct, altering the column to utf8mb4_unicode_ci should fix the issue, yes.

Comment: @Akina so if i set `charset: "utf8mb4", collate: "utf8mb4_unicode_ci",` on table level that should work, right?

Comment: The parameters set to table does not effect the connection settings and are overrided with column settings. So I cannot say does your edition solves current issue and does it will not produce similar issue in some place in the future.